# Why aren't SpilloverCount and SurgeQueueLength available on some of my ELBs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-cloudwatch

Some of my ELBs have SpilloverCount and SurgeQueueLength metrics available in Cloudwatch Metrics, others do not. Why not? I'd like to see these metrics on the ones that don't, as I am troubleshooting latency problems with them.

Comment: maybe there was no Spillover? manual says Reporting criteria: There is a nonzero value. same for SurgeQueueLength

Comment: When you say "available" do you mean "provisioned"/"defined" -- as in, there are no such metrics defined, at all?  Perhaps they're really old ELBs?  Do newly-created balancers show them but old ones don't?  (Random guess).

Comment: What I mean is that when I go to the new Metrics page, https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#metricsV2, and I search for spillover, only some of my ELBs appear in the results. Others do not appear. Maybe it's because they only have zero values. If so, I find that somewhat confusing!